# C# : whats the use of waitHandle when we can use the threadPool Property

Tags: c#

Whats the trade off between using waitHandle and using threadPool's Property  Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread ? 
Considering the fact my methods in threadpool are brief ? does it makes sense to use waitHandle to consider it not waiting ?

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
                             {
                                 DoWork(Top, Bottom);
                             });

if (Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread == false 
                      && SomeotherCondition == false )
{
    // Uses the Dowork
}
```

Redefining the questions: when should one use waitHandle and when IsThreadPoolThread?

Comment: Those two have nothing in common.

Comment: What's the point of a truck when we have an apple?

Comment: Could you please provide code snippets for the two cases you need comparison for as your question description hardly makes any sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `WaitHandle` when you want a thread to wait for some operation to complete. Use `IsThreadPoolThread` when you want to know if a thread is a thread pool thread. To put it another way, use a rocket if you want to go into space, and make a salad if you want to eat vegetables.